# NodeJS Unable to redirect (or even see) some incoming requests

Tags: node.js, ssl

Using [This tutorial](https://contextneutral.com/story/creating-an-https-server-with-nodejs-and-express/?utm=medium) I was able to set up NodeJS with SSL keys.  It creates two http servers (one secure, one not).

```
var app = express();
var sslOptions = {}; // SSL key stuff in here

var https = require('https');
https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(443);

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

Then it checks any incoming request -- if it's not secure, it redirects it to the secure URL

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('request... ' + req.url); // I don't see this 
  if (req.secure) {
    console.log('secure ' + req.url);
    next();
  } else {
    console.log('redirect... https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  }
});
```

I see some requests come in, such as favicon.ico, when I start with a fresh browser. But the actual request to www.mydomain.com appears to bypass this all together (as do the requests I'm making to endpoints).  What's worse is I had this working at one point. Not sure what I did to break it.  Anywho, the result is http://www.example.com trying to hit an endpoint at https://www.example.com/endpoint and it fails (not to mention not loading the secure version of the page).